# change multiple items in a line simultaneously using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a textfile with the following contents

```
C1               NJ_03_PKL_0354   SU1              4.138      0.013      1014.67    1014.658   0          0         
C2               NJ_03_DRG_0079   MS_03_DRN_0369   10         0.013      1014.45    1014.658   0          0         
C3               NJ_03_DRG_0078   MS_03_DRN_0369   4.359      0.013      1014.48    1014.658   0          0         
C4               NJ_03_DRG_0076   MS_03_DRN_0369   10         0.013      1014.67    1014.658   0          0         
C5               NJ_03_PKL_0355   SU2              10         0.013      1032.66    1032.76    0          0         
C6               MS_03_QLD_0352   MS_03_QLD_0419   35.662     0.015      1018.68    1018.4     0          0         
C7               MS_03_QLD_0217   SU4              28.438     0.015      1019.75    1019.111   0          0         
C8               MS_03_FPK_0042   NJ_03_FPK_0013   263.08     0.015      1001.75    999.05     0          0         
MC_03_BDO_0000   MS_03_BDO_0000   MS_03_BDO_0001   53.07      0.015      1023.72    1023.33    0          0
```

and have the following list:

```
listSWMM=['J1','J2','J3', 'J4', 'J5', 'J6', 'J7', 'J8', 'J9', 'J10', 'J11', 'J12','J13',' J14', 'J15','J16','J17', 'J18', 'J19', 'J20', 'J21', 'J22', 'J24', 'J25', 'J26', 'J27','J28',' J29','J30','SU1', 'SU2','SU3', 'SU4', 'SU5', 'SU6', 'SU7', 'SU8', 'SU9', 'SU10', 'SU11', 'SU12','SU13',' SU14', 'SU15','SU16','SU17', 'SU18', 'SU19', 'SU20', 'SU21', 'SU22', 'SU24', 'SU25', 'SU26', 'SU27','SU28',' SU29','SU30','C1', 'C2','C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12','C13',' C14', 'C15','C16','C17', 'C18', 'C19', 'C20', 'C21', 'C22', 'C24', 'C25', 'C26', 'C27','C28',' C29','C30','OR1', 'OR2','OR3', 'OR4', 'OR5', 'OR6', 'OR7', 'OR8', 'OR9', 'OR10', 'OR11', 'OR12','OR13',' OR14', 'OR15','OR16','OR17', 'OR18', 'OR19', 'OR20', 'OR21', 'OR22', 'OR24', 'OR25', 'OR26', 'OR27','OR28',' OR29','OR30','W1', 'W2','W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7', 'W8', 'W9', 'W10', 'W11', 'W12','W13',' W14', 'W15','W16','W17', 'W18', 'W19', 'W20', 'W21', 'W22', 'W24', 'W25', 'W26', 'W27','W28',' W29','W30','OL1', 'OL2','OL3', 'OL4', 'OL5', 'OL6', 'OL7', 'OL8', 'OL9', 'OL10', 'OL11', 'OL12','OL13',' OL14', 'OL15','OL16','OL17', 'OL18', 'OL19', 'OL20', 'OL21', 'OL22', 'OL24', 'OL25', 'OL26', 'OL27','OL28',' OL29','OL30']
```

if there is an element in the list that appears in the line of the textfile, it needs to be changed to '03_element' (e.g. 03_C1).

So line 1 should be

```
03_C1               NJ_03_PKL_0354   03_SU1              4.138      0.013      1014.67    1014.658   0          0
```

I have tried the following:

```
import re
infile=open(r'CONDUITS.txt','r')
listSWMM=['J1','J2','J3', 'J4', 'J5', 'J6', 'J7', 'J8', 'J9', 'J10', 'J11', 'J12','J13',' J14', 'J15','J16','J17', 'J18', 'J19', 'J20', 'J21', 'J22', 'J24', 'J25', 'J26', 'J27','J28',' J29','J30','SU1', 'SU2','SU3', 'SU4', 'SU5', 'SU6', 'SU7', 'SU8', 'SU9', 'SU10', 'SU11', 'SU12','SU13',' SU14', 'SU15','SU16','SU17', 'SU18', 'SU19', 'SU20', 'SU21', 'SU22', 'SU24', 'SU25', 'SU26', 'SU27','SU28',' SU29','SU30','C1', 'C2','C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12','C13',' C14', 'C15','C16','C17', 'C18', 'C19', 'C20', 'C21', 'C22', 'C24', 'C25', 'C26', 'C27','C28',' C29','C30','OR1', 'OR2','OR3', 'OR4', 'OR5', 'OR6', 'OR7', 'OR8', 'OR9', 'OR10', 'OR11', 'OR12','OR13',' OR14', 'OR15','OR16','OR17', 'OR18', 'OR19', 'OR20', 'OR21', 'OR22', 'OR24', 'OR25', 'OR26', 'OR27','OR28',' OR29','OR30','W1', 'W2','W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7', 'W8', 'W9', 'W10', 'W11', 'W12','W13',' W14', 'W15','W16','W17', 'W18', 'W19', 'W20', 'W21', 'W22', 'W24', 'W25', 'W26', 'W27','W28',' W29','W30','OL1', 'OL2','OL3', 'OL4', 'OL5', 'OL6', 'OL7', 'OL8', 'OL9', 'OL10', 'OL11', 'OL12','OL13',' OL14', 'OL15','OL16','OL17', 'OL18', 'OL19', 'OL20', 'OL21', 'OL22', 'OL24', 'OL25', 'OL26', 'OL27','OL28',' OL29','OL30']

for line in infile:
    for item in listSWMM:
        if item in line:            
            y=re.sub(item,"03_{}".format(item),line)
            print(y)
```

But the output only changes one item in the line at a time. I want both items to change simultaneously

Comment: Each time you call `re.sub()` you're working from the original line, not the result of the previous substitution.

Comment: Use `line = re.sub(..., line)` to accumulate the changes.

Answer (score 2):

You keep doing the substitutions to the original line, not the result of the previous substitution, so you're not accumulating all the changes. You should assign the result of the substitution back to the `line` variable.

```
for line in infile:
    for item in listSWMM:
        line=line.replace(item, "03_" + item) # no need to use a regular expression
    print(line)
```

But instead of looping over `listSWMM`, you should turn it into a regular expression that performs all the substitutions at once.

```
rx = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, listSWMM)))

for line in infile:
    y = rx.sub(r'03_\g<0>', line)
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide the data by the columns.

```py
lines = []
index = [17, 34, 51, 62, 73, 84, 95, 106]
with open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for s in f:
        row = []
        o = 0
        for i in range(len(index)):
            row.append(s[o:index[i]].strip())
            o = index[i]
        row.append(s[o:].strip())
        lines.append(row)
```

And, construct the *listSWMM* elements with a *for-loop*.
Or, in this case a *list comprehension*.

```py
v = [x + str(y) for x in ['J', 'SU', 'C', 'OR', 'W', 'OL']
                for y in range(1, 31)]
```

Next, *find-and-replace* each value.

```py
for i in range(len(lines)):
    for j in range(len(lines[i])):
        for e in v:
            lines[i][j] = lines[i][j].replace(e, '03_' + e)
```

And finally, format the data, and write the file.

```py
with open('data-new.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as w:
    for line in lines:
        s = ('{:<17}' * 3).format(*line[0:3])
        s += ('{:<11}' * 5).format(*line[3:8])
        s += f'{line[8]:<10}'
        w.write(s + '\n')
```

Here is the data after formatting.

```
03_C1            NJ_03_PKL_0354   03_SU1           4.138      0.013      1014.67    1014.658   0          0         
03_C2            NJ_03_DRG_0079   MS_03_DRN_0369   10         0.013      1014.45    1014.658   0          0         
03_C3            NJ_03_DRG_0078   MS_03_DRN_0369   4.359      0.013      1014.48    1014.658   0          0         
03_C4            NJ_03_DRG_0076   MS_03_DRN_0369   10         0.013      1014.67    1014.658   0          0         
03_C5            NJ_03_PKL_0355   03_SU2           10         0.013      1032.66    1032.76    0          0         
03_C6            MS_03_QLD_0352   MS_03_QLD_0419   35.662     0.015      1018.68    1018.4     0          0         
03_C7            MS_03_QLD_0217   03_SU4           28.438     0.015      1019.75    1019.111   0          0         
03_C8            MS_03_FPK_0042   NJ_03_FPK_0013   263.08     0.015      1001.75    999.05     0          0         
MC_03_BDO_0000   MS_03_BDO_0000   MS_03_BDO_0001   53.07      0.015      1023.72    1023.33    0          0
```